# Get only IPV4 Addres and Exclude IPv6 from WMI PHP

Tags: php, wmi, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I Have Script to get IP Address based on PHP and WMI like this:

Get Active Adapter Network

```
function get_server_network_adapter() {

    $pc = "."; 
    $obj = new COM ("winmgmts:\\\\".$pc."\\root\\cimv2");
    $wmi_network_rec = $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from  Win32_NetworkAdapter Where NetConnectionStatus = 2");

    foreach ($wmi_network_rec as $wmi_call) {
        $adapter = $wmi_call->Name;
        return $adapter;
    }
}
```

and Get IPAdress of Active Adapter

```
function get_server_ip() 
{
    $adapter = get_server_network_adapter();
    $pc = "."; 
    $obj = new COM ("winmgmts:\\\\".$pc."\\root\\cimv2");
    $wmi_server_ip = $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from  Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where Description = '$adapter'");

    foreach ($wmi_server_ip as $wmi_call) {
        $ip = $wmi_call->IPAddress;

        foreach ($ip as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

The Result of my code above is **192.168.1.103fe80::e9ad:9bb:e359:a122**

However what I want is to only get the IPv4 like **192.168.1.103**

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Abstractedly from `php` tag, `IPAddress` property is simple an **array** in *any used language*. Read about it in MSDN article [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **IPAddress**
>
> Data type: **string array**
>  Access type: Read-only
>  Qualifiers:
>   [MappingStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393650(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   
> ("Win32Registry|System\CurrentControlSet\Services|Parameters\Tcpip|IPAddress")
>
> Array of all of the IP addresses associated with the current network
>   adapter. This property can contain either IPv6 addresses or IPv4
>   addresses. For more information, see [IPv6 and IPv4 Support in
>   WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822883(v=vs.85).aspx).

However (above your question topic), identifying a network adapter via `Name` or `Description` property does not seem to be a good idea. Use `InterfaceIndex` property instead. Read [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN articles:

> **InterfaceIndex**
>
> Data type: **uint32**
>  Access type: Read-only
>
> Index value that **uniquely identifies the local network interface**. The
>   value in this property is the same as the value in the
>   `InterfaceIndex` property in the instance of [Win32_IP4RouteTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394162(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   that represents the network interface in the route table.